# qual a utilidade de classes aninhadas em python?para que eu usaria algo do tipo?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

não consigo encontrar muita coisa do tipo para python, eu sei que dá para fazer isso e sei como fazer, mas não sei porque alguém iria querer fazer isso, visto que a classe interna é incapaz de acessar os atributos e métodos da classe externa, coisa que eu normalmente usaria uma herança para resolver, mas tirando a herança de jogo, usar isso tem alguma utlilidade? vi meu professor fazendo num curso de Django que estou fazendo atualmente.

Comment: Essa pergunta se bem trabalhada tem o potencial de se tornar uma pergunta muito boa e gerar boas repostas. Perguntar a esmo sobre a utilidade de classes aninhadas é escopo indefinido, talvez se associar quais as vantagens  do uso de classes aninhadas a um design pattern especifico, por exemplo Builder, junto de um exemplo de uso.

Answer (score 1):

Nâo sei exatamente em Python, mas isso é um problema geral de computação.

Normalmente se faz classe aninhadas para se organizar o código.

imagine que você tem uma classe `GoogleAPIClient`, e digamos que as respostas você deseja guardar em um objeto `Response`

Este objeto `Response` não é um objeto `Response` qualquer, mas dedicado, e se você nomear esta classe com um nome comum, pode colidir com outro `Response` de outra coisa.

Você pode nomear esse response como `GoogleAPIClientResponse`, mas o que se faz normalmente é aninhar, assim, dentro do seu `GoogleAPIClient` você referencia isso apenas como `Response`.

Algumas linguagens ainda permitem que classes aninhadas sejam privadas, ou seja, você nâo pode gerar uma instância desse response fora de `GoogleAPIClient`.